# Integrating Mixpanel with Shopify

Tags: javascript, analytics, shopify, mixpanel

Hi I am currently tracking users who add item to their cart and then view their cart summary page. I have inserted the following code in my cart.liquid file;

```
<!-- Begin Mixpanel integration code -->
 <script type="text/javascript">

  mixpanel.track("Checkout",
        { "Checkout Total": "{{ product.price | money }}" });
 </script>
<!-- End Mixpanel integration code -->
```

The event 'Checkout' is coming through fine on my mixpanel dashboard however i am unable to get the property of { product.price | money } to come through. Is there are a reason why 'checkout total' comes up blank? How do i get shopify to send to mixpanel the price of the item added to cart?

I am trying to track the price of the product which is located in the product.liquid file:

```
      <p>
        {% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
          <span class="actual-price" itemprop="price">{{ product.price | money }}</span>&nbsp;<span class="compare-price"></span>
        {% else %}
          <span class="actual-price" itemprop="price">{{ product.price | money }}</span>{% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}&nbsp;
          <span class="compare-price">Was {{ product.compare_at_price_max | money }}</span>{% endif %}         
        {% endif %}
      </p>
```

Also tried with variant.price but it still didn't work;

mixpanel.track("Checkout",
        { "Checkout Total": "{{ variant.price }}" });

Thanks

Comment: Add more code so we can see the whole picture.

Comment: Sure. I have added in the code from the product.liquid file which has the price located in it.

Comment: Did you try with variant.price?

Comment: No it still did not work.

Comment: See what objects are available within the cart.liquid then and play with them